# Optimizing the blog loop

Tags: posts, loop, wp-reset-postdata

I've got such post loop:

```
 <?php
global $post;
$post = $post_object;
setup_postdata( $post );
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                <div class="row single-post">
                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        <div class="date"><?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-9 content">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => "img-responsive post-image")); ?>
                                    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                                    <p class="single-content"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                    <div class="post-meta">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Czytaj więcej" class="read-more">>> Czytaj więcej..</a>
                                            <p>Kategorie wpisu: <?php $category = get_the_category(); if($category[0]){ echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>'; }    ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <div class="center"><?php my_pagination(); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>

        <div class="center">Nope:( no posts yet.</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The question is - can i somehow optimize it? I need to use setup/reset postdata as i use it to generate list of most often viewed posts.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **do not use `query_posts`**

use `get_posts` or `new WP_Query` instead.

If you want to show only most viewed posts, you'll need to add action ( for ex. wp ) check if your on single post page and update that post meta `views` ( +1 ).
Then you could do something like these

```
$topViewedPosts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'views',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // sort by views
    'order' => 'DESC', // sort 3 - 2 - 1
    'posts_per_page' => 5
) );
if( $topViewedPosts->have_posts() )
    while( $topViewedPosts->have_posts() ) : $topViewedPosts->the_post();
        // your content here
    endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

May be i misunderstood what you'r looking for.. try to explane better than..

Comment: okey.. so :) query from my code should show all posts. yet.. through setup_postdata and reset_postdata I collect data for other query (which works fine). Ive tried to use get_posts unfortunatelly with that my pagination didnt work at all :|

Comment: So you'r ploblem is with pagination ? try to do `wp_reset_postdata()` after calling pagination.. as i recall default wp pagination uses `global $wp_query;` and your resetting it before your pagination uses it ( at least i think so.. )